# FFT-results in python dependend on linspace chosen?

Tags: python, fft

I'm very new to Python and I have a basic understanding problem. To me it seems that the result of an FFT is just based on the linspace chosen by oneself.

```
# Number of samplepoints
N = 600
# sample spacing
T = 1.0 / 800.0
x = p.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)
y = p.sin(50.0 * 2.0*p.pi*x) + 0.5*p.sin(80.0 * 2.0*p.pi*x)
yf = p.fft(y)
xf = p.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), N/2)

plt.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[0:N/2]))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

By running this fft as an example I get two spikes, at 50 and at 80 Hz. When I change xf to:

```
xf = p.linspace(0.0, 5.0/(2.0*T), N/2)
```

the spikes are around 250 and 400 Hz.

Doesn't this mean, that I have to know the correct results beforehand (in this case the frequencies of the two sinus waves the input signal consists of), so that I can later adjust the scaling of the axis to fit those results? Probably not, so I'd be glad if someone could explain this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must calculate the correct frequencies depending on sample rate, number of samples and samples used in the fft (NFFT). The FFT algorithm does not know what time-scale you are operating in. For example, the frequency axis could also be given in angular frequency in which case you would just scale the axis with 2*pi.

Therefore, you must know the sample rate and number of samples of the input signal to create a correct frequency axis for the FFT result - you do not, however, need to know anything about the shape of the input signal (disregarding aliasing concerns).

The frequencies [Hz] can be calculated using:

```
dt = 0.0001 # your T
Fs = 1 / dt # sample rate
xt = np.arange (0, 10, dt)
nt = len (xt) # length of time series, your N

# make signal
st = .5 * np.sin (50 * 2 * np.pi * xt) + .5 * np.sin (80 * 2 * np.pi * xt)

# take fourier transform and shift frequency spectra
S  = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft (st))

## make argument array, frequency [Hz]
#
# extending from -Fs/2 to Fs/2, the Nyquist frequency, with the same
# number of samples as in the time series (xt and st).

freqs = Fs * np.linspace (-1/2, 1/2, nt)

# plot absolute value, scaled with number of samples
# ( note that it is also interesting to plot the complex angle
#   using np.angle () ). together they make a bode-plot.

plt.plot (freqs, np.abs(S) / nt)
plt.xlabel ('Frequency [Hz]')
```

Answer (score -1):

You are calculating correctly the FFT of a sine function in:

```
yf = p.fft(y)
```

Then you are ploting it against an list of values constructed using linespace which is wrong. You should plot the magnitude of FFT against its frequency. See [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html#numpy.fft.fft) example for details.